# Как реализовать ожидание основного потока завершения загрузки в отдельном потоке?

Tags: java

Что-то на подобии:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // Загрузка
            }
        }.start();

        // Ожидание конца загрузки
        // Действия после загрузки
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужен метод join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread th = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loading();
            }
        };

        th.start();

        try {
            th.join();// Ожидание конца загрузки
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Действия после загрузки

    }

    private void loading(){
        // Загрузка
    }
```